# What is the regex for the text between quotes?

Tags: php, regex

Ok, I have tried looking at other answers, but couldn't get mine solved. So here is the code:

```
{"chg":"-0.71","vol":"40700","time":"11.08.2011 12:29:09","high":"1.417","low":"1.360","last":"1.400","pcl":"1.410","turnover":"56,560.25"}
```

I need to get every second value in the quotes (as the `"name"` values are constant). I actually worked out that I need to get text between `:"` and `"` but i can't manage to write a regex for that.

EDIT: I'm doing preg_match_all in php. And its between `:"` and `"`, not `"` and `"` as someone else edited.

Comment: What language are we talking here?

Comment: I've updated my answer after your update, basically you just had to add : to the front of the regexp, the regexp does use matching though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why on *earth* would you attempt to parse JSON with regular expressions? PHP already [parses JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) *properly*, with *built-in* functionality.

Code:

```
<?php
$input = '{"chg":"-0.71","vol":"40700","time":"11.08.2011 12:29:09","high":"1.417","low":"1.360","last":"1.400","pcl":"1.410","turnover":"56,560.25"}';
print_r(json_decode($input, true));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [chg] => -0.71
    [vol] => 40700
    [time] => 11.08.2011 12:29:09
    [high] => 1.417
    [low] => 1.360
    [last] => 1.400
    [pcl] => 1.410
    [turnover] => 56,560.25
)
```

[Live demo.](http://codepad.org/HgPNgmVF)

Comment: This answer is **wrong**. *Everyone* knows you parse *anything* and *everything* with regex, including HTML, JSON, CSV, Medical Records, etc. Everything. `</sarcasm>`

Comment: @Christian: I parsed your mum's face with regular expressions, and look what happened!

Comment: @Christian: Just look! `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score -1):

You may need to escape characters or add  a forward slash to the front or back depending on your language. But it's basically:

```
:"([^"].*?)"
```

or

```
/:"([^"].*?)"/
```

I've test this in groovy as below and it works.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

String test='{"chg":"-0.71","vol":"40700","time":"11.08.2011 12:29:09","high":"1.417","low":"1.360","last":"1.400","pcl":"1.410","turnover":"56,560.25"}'

  // Create a pattern to match breaks
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(':"([^"]*)"');
  // Split input with the pattern
  // Run some matches
  Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
  while (m.find())
      System.out.println("Found comment: "+m.group().replace('"','').replace(":",""));
```

Output was:

```
Found comment: -0.71
Found comment: 40700
Found comment: 11.08.2011 12:29:09
Found comment: 1.417
Found comment: 1.360
Found comment: 1.400
Found comment: 1.410
Found comment: 56,560.25
```

**PHP Example**

```
<?php
$subject = '{"chg":"-0.71","vol":"40700","time":"11.08.2011 12:29:09","high":"1.417","low":"1.360","last":"1.400","pcl":"1.410","turnover":"56,560.25"}';
$pattern = '/(?<=:")[^"]*/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Output is:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => -0.71 [1] => 8 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 40700 [1] => 22 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 11.08.2011 12:29:09 [1] => 37 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 1.417 [1] => 66 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 1.360 [1] => 80 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 1.400 [1] => 95 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 1.410 [1] => 109 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 56,560.25 [1] => 128 ) ) )
```

Comment: Note: in this solution we have to replace the `"` and the `:` in the final string with an empty string. If back references work then use `'(?<=:")[^"]*'` as the regex instead.

Comment: Ohh, sorry to bother you with that. Got it.

Comment: I've added my PHP test. The array that is returned contains an array for each match. You basically only need the first element of each array in there which is the vale.